# Google Cloud Trace not working for Spring Boot 3 Service Deployed on GKE

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, open-telemetry, spring-boot-3

I have a microservice deployed on GKE. I was setting up logging and trace, and logs are correctly displayed on Google Cloud Logging, but the traces are not showing up in Cloud Trace. It's a maven Spring Boot 3 project, so Sleuth is no longer supported and I figured I should use OpenTelemetry due to how much documentation there is on the subject, and I've been tinkering around with the configuration.

Since the traces work fine for local logging exporter, I figure I must be missing some component for the traces to propagate correctly in deployment (using a different exporter). It's definitely not a ServiceAccount IAM issues since the ServiceAccount should have all the necessary privileges to write traces and logs.

Here're the dependencies I use for tracing:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.opentelemetry.instrumentation</groupId>
    <artifactId>opentelemetry-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.opentelemetry.instrumentation</groupId>
    <artifactId>opentelemetry-spring-webmvc-6.0</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.opentelemetry.instrumentation</groupId>
    <artifactId>opentelemetry-spring-webflux-5.3</artifactId>
</dependency>

<!-- OpenTelemetry exporter -->
<!-- replace this default exporter with your OpenTelemetry exporter (ex. otlp/zipkin/..) -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.opentelemetry</groupId>
    <artifactId>opentelemetry-exporter-logging</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud.opentelemetry</groupId>
    <artifactId>exporter-auto</artifactId>
    <version>0.27.0-alpha</version>
</dependency>
```

And here's the application.yaml configs added for configure traces

```
otel:
  service:
    name: profile-service
  traces:
    sampler:
      probability: 1.0
    exporter: logging
  metrics:
    exporter: logging
  logs:
    exporter: logging
```

This works fine locally, and I'm seeing traces/spans/metrics, but in deployment the exporter fields are otel.traces.exporter=google_cloud_trace and otel.metrics.exporter=google_cloud_monitoring, as noted by the first resource I list below.

Here are the resources I used:
[Google Cloud Trace Exporter](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/opentelemetry-operations-java/blob/main/exporters/auto/README.md)
[Spring Boot Instrumenting with OpenTelemetry](https://opentelemetry.io/docs/languages/java/automatic/spring-boot/)
and other Github discussions related to the topic which've led me to the current situation. I'd appreciate any guidance/feedback.

Comment: What are the errors from OpenTelemetry pods?